# How to remove ASCII Spark Banner from Console?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to remove the ASCII Spark text from the console. Is there a config file somewhere or a command I can use to remove this? I'm trying to declutter the outputs.

[Here is a picture of the text I'm talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU6dY.jpg)

Any commands that help remove excess bloat from the console is appreciated!

Comment: why do you want to remove spark logo from console ?

Comment: @howie Ideally I'd just want to type 'spark-shell' and then just have the spark prompt pop up. I know in the Spring framework there's a flag in the config file where you can disable the Banner, I figured there might be an option somewhere in Spark. It's just personal preference.